# ReactJs Link Not Able To Navigate To Respective Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using "`Link`" in my component to navigate and pass respective data through props to other component.
I have below primary component as `AllSuppliers` which is using Link to navigate to `EditSupplier` component.

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { EditSupplier } from "./EditSupplier";
function AllSuppliers() {
    const [suppliers, setstate] = useState([])   
    useEffect(() => {        
        axios.get('http://localhost:62815/api/values/GetAllSuppliers')
            .then(x => {                
                setstate(x.data)            
            }
            )
            .catch(error => {
                alert(error);                
            });;
    },[]);
    return (
        <>
            <table style={{width: '50%'}}>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>
                    Supplier Id
                </th>
                <th>
                    Supplier Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Edit
                </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                
                {                    
                    suppliers.map((supplier)=> {
                        return <tr>
                            <td>
                            {supplier.sup_Id}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            {supplier.sup_ShortCode}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <Router>
                                <Link to={{ pathname: '/EditSupplier', supplierProps: { name: 'bar'} }}>Edit</Link>
                                </Router>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    })
                }
               
            </table>
        </>
    )
}

export default AllSuppliers
```

When Clicked On Edit Link , component not getting navigated. Just browser url is getting changed.

[image]

As seen in the image , only browser url is getting changed but cannot see contents from `EditSuppliers`. Contents in the image are from `AllSuppliers` component.
What could be the cause?

**EDIT 1 :-**

I tried to wrap my App with Router in App.js as -

```
import './App.css';
import AllSuppliers from './Components/AllSuppliers'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
      <AllSuppliers></AllSuppliers>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I observed the same behavior.

Also I tried wrap Router inside `AllSuppliers` - before and after `<table> </table>`

I observed same behavior in this case too.

**Edit 2 :-**

```
AllSuppliers.Js



import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { EditSupplier } from "./EditSupplier";
function AllSuppliers() {
    const [suppliers, setstate] = useState([])   
    useEffect(() => {        
        axios.get('http://localhost:62815/api/values/GetAllSuppliers')
            .then(x => {                
                setstate(x.data)            
            }
            )
            .catch(error => {
                alert(error);                
            });;
    },[]);
    return (
        <>
     
            <table style={{width: '50%'}}>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>
                    Supplier Id
                </th>
                <th>
                    Supplier Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Edit
                </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                
                {                    
                    suppliers.map((supplier)=> {
                        return <tr>
                            <td>
                            {supplier.sup_Id}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            {supplier.sup_ShortCode}
                            </td>
                            <td>                            
                                <Link to={{ pathname: '/EditSupplier', supplierProps: { name: 'bar'} }}>Edit</Link>                         
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    })
                }
               
            </table>
           
        </>
    )
}

export default AllSuppliers
```

Comment: Where is `AllSuppliers` being rendered in relation to your main `Router`?

Comment: AllSuppliers is rendered directly from App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are rendering each link into its own `Router` context when mapping each `supplier`.

```
suppliers.map((supplier)=> {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{supplier.sup_Id}</td>
      <td>{supplier.sup_ShortCode}</td>
      <td>
        <Router> // <-- router context
          <Link
            to={{
              pathname: '/EditSupplier',
              supplierProps: {
                name: 'bar',
              },
            }}
          >
            Edit
          </Link>
        </Router>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
})
```

The problem here is that each `Link` will use the routing context of the closest `Router` above it in the ReactTree, so you'll see the URL change in the address bar but the `Router` handling all your application's routes doesn't get updated.

You also appear to be missing any sort of *actual* routing in your app.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
      <AllSuppliers></AllSuppliers>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Solution

Remove the extraneous `Router` components. Just ensure that there is ***at least*** one `Router` wrapping your app to provide the routing context.

```
suppliers.map((supplier)=> {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{supplier.sup_Id}</td>
      <td>{supplier.sup_ShortCode}</td>
      <td>
        <Link
          to={{
            pathname: '/EditSupplier',
            supplierProps: {
              name: 'bar',
            },
          }}
        >
          Edit
        </Link>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
})
```

Define the routes for your app to render.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/EditSupplier" component={EditSupplier} />
          <Route path="/" component={AllSuppliers} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you please look at Edit1 , where I have removed Router from each Link and placed it outside. But I observe the same behaviour.

Comment: @CSharper The `Router` wrapping `App` or `AllSuppliers` would be correct. Did you remove all the `Router` components wrapping each `Link`? You really only need one `Router` for the entire app.

Comment: Yes , I removed. In Edit2 , I have pasted modified AllSuppliers.js

Comment: @CSharper Where is your main `Router` where your `Route` components are defined? If you've no routes then no amount of `Link`s will make anything else render.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to set up `routes` in `app.js`. Then only Your link will work

```
import './App.css';
import AllSuppliers from './Components/AllSuppliers'
import { EditSupplier } from "./Components/EditSupplier";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link ,Switch} from "react-router-dom";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
      <Switch>
         <Route exact path='/' component={AllSuppliers} />
         <Route exact path='/EditSupplier' component={EditSupplier} />
      </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In your code

```
 <Router>
      <AllSuppliers></AllSuppliers>
      </Router>
```

You are just rendering single component `AllSuppliers`. Whenever the roue changes  You will only see `AllSuppliers`